# angular2 http interceptor and inject SlimLoadingBarService does not work?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services, es6-class

I write a http intercpetor,it is like this:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { SlimLoadingBarService } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';
// ... other imports in here

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService extends Http {
    private apiEndpoint: string;

    constructor(
        @Inject(CONFIG_TOKEN) config: Config,
        private backend: ConnectionBackend,
        private defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
        private slimLoadingBarService: SlimLoadingBarService
    ) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
        this.apiEndpoint = config.apiEndpoint;
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        this.beforeRequest();
        return super.get(this.getFullUrl(url), this.requestOptions(options))
            // ...
    }

    private beforeRequest(): void {
        // this is not work
        this.slimLoadingBarService.start();
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

My  app.module provide config like this:

```
{
    provide: HttpInterceptorService,
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => {
        return new HttpInterceptorService(CONFIG, backend, 
            defaultOptions, new SlimLoadingBarService);
    },
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}
```

Now, this Http interceptor is worker,But the `SlimLoadingBarService` doew not work.

I feel should be wrong to pass the `new SlimLoadingBarService` lead, but the direct transmission `SlimLoadingBarService`, the same will be given, and now stuck in this place do not know how to continue.

There is no error message, but loadingbar(`SlimLoadingBarService`) does not show up.

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: This question is quite cryptic, please elaborate it in order to get some help, describe your problem, errors encountered, etc. "not working" is not a description of the problem.

Comment: @Karbos538 It's no error message, but loadingbar does not show up.

Comment: @n00dl3 It does not show any mistakes, can be the correct implementation, but loadingbar can not be displayed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
{
  provide: HttpInterceptorService,
  useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, slimLoadingBarService: SlimLoadingBarService) => {
    return new HttpInterceptorService(CONFIG, backend, 
        defaultOptions, slimLoadingBarService);
  },
  deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, SlimLoadingBarService]
}
```

Comment: Thank you reminder, here is indeed a problem, but the main reason is that my http interceptor call the problem has been resolved.